# How to copy and paste an image including cropping information in google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a google script that involves copying an image from one document into another. It might be an inlineImage or a positionedImage in the original, but I make it a positionedImage in the new document. I'm able to extract it from the document just fine, and get the height and width information: but I can't figure out how to copy the cropping (or for that matter, then apply it to the image when I paste it into the new document). It's giving me some very distorted images!
Is there support for copying the cropping from images? How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's not currently possible, but there are several relevant feature requests in place, if anyone else is having trouble with this:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36758779

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36813580

Comment: Do you mean within Google Docs? Yes, it's possible; when you copy manually, the cropping information is retained. But as I need to do it from 12-20 documents to around 25 documents, I was hoping to do it programmatically...

Comment: For now, my solution has been to crop the image externally to google docs before putting it in the original 12-20 documents. As I'm not the only one creating them, it's not the most convenient, but seems like the best option.